# Error in randomForest, NA, missing values in object

Tags: r, random-forest

When I tried

```
marketing.rf <- randomForest(formula = as.numeric(y) ~., data = marketing.train, importance = TRUE)
```

it shows the error:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(`as.numeric(y)` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, : missing values in object
```

and when I tried:

```
y.val <- ifelse(marketing.train$y=="yes", 1,0)
marketing.rf <-  randomForest(formula = as.numeric(y.val) ~., data = marketing.train, importance = TRUE)
```

It shows another error:

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

I tried to use `as.factor(y)`, but it shows a similar error. 
I used `dput(marketing.test$y)` to look at the values, but simply can't find any NA or invalid value in it.

I'm quite new to R, can someone help me fix this? Thanks!!!

Here are sample train data:

```
age job             marital     edu         default   balance  housing   loan   y
58  management      married     tertiary    no        2143     yes       no     no
33  entrepreneur    married     secondary   no        2        yes       yes    no
33  unknown         single      unknown     no        1        no        no     no
42  entrepreneur    divorced    tertiary    yes       2        yes       no     no
```

Comment: You have missing values in the "y" column so it doesn't know how to train on these rows of data. Use `train_dat <- marketing.train[!is.na(marketing.train$y),]` to remove missing rows and then use that in your above algos as the data set

Comment: Thanks @MDEWITT !
However, now it shows this error:
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : length of response must be the same as predictors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example with reprex data. Without your data I can't make a perfect answer, but if you follow this logic you should be ok.

```
library(randomForest)

# Generate Some Fake Data
fake_data <- data.frame(
  age = runif(500, 30, 65),
  martial = sample(c("single", "married", "divorced"), 500, T),
  default = sample(c("yes", "no"), 500, T),
  balance = runif(500,0,2100),
  housing = sample(c("yes", "no"), 500, T),
  loan = sample(c("yes", "no"), 500, T),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Add some missing data for example

fake_data[sample(x = 1:500, size = 5), "loan"] <- NA

# Check for NAs

fake_data_2 <- fake_data[!is.na(fake_data$loan),]

cat("You have removed ", nrow(fake_data)-nrow(fake_data_2), " records")

# Add target and make sure it is a factor

fake_data_2$y <- as.factor(fake_data_2$loan)

# Make characters into factors
library(dplyr)

fake_data_2 <- fake_data_2 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

fit <- randomForest(y ~ ., data = fake_data_2)
```

This will yield a valid random forest model.

Comment: @Andrea good to hear! If it works could you please accept the answer so others know it solved your issues (little green check mark below the up/down arrows on this post),